Launching already running programs from shell creates notifications instead of raising the window in 24.04
In Ubuntu 22.04 and older, when launching a program from the shell, the program's window would pop up in all cases.
In Ubuntu 24.04, we get a notification instead that the window is "ready" if the program has already been running. You have to click on the notification to be taken to the window of the program. Is there a way to make it behave like older Ubuntu versions?
I tried it with various shells and consistently got the same results.

Turns out there are many Gnome shell extensions made for solving this exact problem. The one I used was "Steal my focus window".
